# Push image to gcr.io without gcloud

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

I am trying to push image to gcr.io accroding to: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication (Using a JSON key file part). But i receive error: "denied: Unable to access the repository, please check that you have permission to access it."
I have tryied with default service account and created new account(with Editor and Storage Admin roles) - no result. Do i miss something?

UPD: reason was json key file was corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you send an email to gcr-contact@google.com with the image that you're trying to push (including projectID)?

Comment: Thanks for help, jsand!

Comment: Happy to help :)